# How Can use Espresso 2 (for tests) with extends Application (android.app.Application)?

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle, android-espresso

I have gradle android-project.
My project work, and my espresso-tests work too.

But If I adding my implementation android.app.Application (extends Application and `<application android:name=".AppInstance" ...` in AndroidManifest) - throw - tests not found, when I start their, by connectedAndroidTest.

How Can I use android.app.Application (extends Application) with library Espresso 2?

I found goode example with espresso 2 and extends Application (http://engineering.circle.com/instrumentation-testing-with-dagger-mockito-and-espresso/), but tests in this example do not work :(

Comment: "but tests in this example do not work" -- what happens to them?

Comment: when I run the gradle task "connectedAndroidTest" - result: tests not found

Comment: :app:connectedAndroidTest
Tests on HTC One SV - 4.2.2 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[HTC One SV - 4.2.2] [31mFAILED [0m
No tests found.
:app:connectedAndroidTest FAILED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me - https://github.com/bryanstern/dagger-instrumentation-example/issues/1

I must to add some code to `build.gradle`:

```
debugCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
debugCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
debugCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.17'

debugCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
}
debugCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
```